# Array datatype convertion in Laravel v5.4 PHP

Tags: php, laravel, type-conversion

Controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestDBController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $db_ext = \DB::connection('extdb');
        $customer = $db_ext->table('customer')->get();
        var_dump($customer);
        // var_dump($customer);
        return view('customers.index', ['customer' => $customer]);
    }
}
```

View

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="kunder-table">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobil</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Address2</th>
        <th>Address3</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($customer as $customer)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $customer->customerid !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->name !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->email !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->mobile !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->adress1 !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->adress2 !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->adress3 !!}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is "var_dump" result.

```
    object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[261]
          protected 'items' => 
            array (size=365)
              0 => 
                object(stdClass)[262]
                  public 'BANKACCOUNT' => string '' (length=0)
                  public 'CUSTOMERID' => int 10000
                  ...
```

I got the final result as **"Undefined property: stdClass::$customerid**.
but there are also have customerid in each table fields. 
So how could I get correct list view? thanks.

Comment: could be you need $customer->id

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: try with replace CUSTOMERID from customerid

Comment: 'CUSTOMERID' and others in that case **are case sensitive** So correct the `$customer->customerid`  to `$customer->CUSTOMERID`

Comment: @Ross this is version 5.4.

Comment: In foreach loop, you are using the same name of array and values parameter. Hence it is trying to find out the property of Collection not an element from an array of objects. Please check below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try with the below changes:

In `TestDBController`

```
return view('customers.index', ['customers' => $customer]);
```

In view File

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $customer->customerid !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->navn !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->email !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->mobile !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->adress1 !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->adress2 !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $customer->adress3 !!}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Here in your controller section, you are passing the values in `customer` variable and in view for `foreach` loop you are using the same name.

The default syntax of `foreach` loop is:

`foreach($array as $values)`

and according to your code, you are using the same variable as your array of collection.